# What is the origin of the OBAFGKM classification system?

Tags: star, classification

Once a body has been identified as a star it is classified into a subsection of either O,B,A,F,G,K or M (I think there are also 3 more letters recently added)

What is the origin of this classification system? Do each of the letters stand for anything?

[image: star classification]

Comment: Just an interesting note : The mnemonic used to remember the sequence is "O Be A Fine Girl Kiss Me"

Comment: "O Be A Fine Girl Kiss Me" - to which my ninth grade Earth Sciences teacher added "Right Now" punctuated with a final "Smack."

Answer (score 9):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification) on stellar classification has the full list of letters:

| Class | Surface Temperature | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O | > 33,000 K |  |
| B | 10,000 - 33,000 K |  |
| A | 7500 - 10,000 K |  |
| F | 6000 - 7500 K |  |
| G | 5200 - 6000 K |  |
| K | 3700 - 5200 K |  |
| M | 2000 - 3700 K |  |
| L | 1300 - 2000 K | L T and Y are those new letters |
| T | 700 - 1300 K |  |
| Y | < 700 K |  |

### History

[This Cornell doc](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/148-people-in-astronomy/history-of-astronomy/general-questions/988-what-is-the-origin-of-the-stellar-classification-system-obafgkm-intermediate) explains much of the history behind the system:

> In the 1890s, many scientists were interested in developing a classification scheme for the stars. Edward C. Pickering at Harvard University, together with his assistant Williamina P. Fleming, assigned stars a letter according to how much Hydrogen could be observed in their spectra: stars labeled A had the most Hydrogen, B the next most, and so on through the alphabet. There were 22 types in all: this scheme was rather cumbersome, and it wasn't clear what its physical significance was.

> In 1901, another of Pickering's assistants, Annie Jump Cannon, also begun to work on the classification sequence. Her meticulous observations led her to simplify the 22-type scheme into a simple sequence of *temperature*: OBAFGKM. Not only was the scheme much simpler than the previous, but it related the amount of hydrogen observed to a physical property of the stars for the first time.

Comment: She rearranged the previous scale, and skipped or merged some entries?